# Challenge a .name registration?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

The [Wikipedia page on .name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.name) says the following:

> **Registration restrictions:** No prior restriction on registration, but registrations can be challenged if not by or on behalf of individual with name similar to that of domain, or fictional character in which registrant has rights

But there's no further info on how this actually works.

Can a .name domain registration be challenged, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about the UDRP:

> To invoke the policy, a trademark owner should either (a) file a complaint in a court of proper jurisdiction against the domain-name holder (or where appropriate an in-rem action concerning the domain name) or (b) in cases of abusive registration submit a complaint to an approved dispute-resolution service provider (see below for a list and links).

http://www.icann.org/en/help/dndr/udrp

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the UDRP. I've never before had to deal with any kind of legal action, and option b) involves a wad of cash. So I suppose this is really only attractive to companies defending trademarks, and not so much to individuals? Which is a shame, because I was under the impression .name was targeted at individuals.

Comment: Honestly you are not losing anything by not having a .name domain name. .name is like the worst TLD ever. Barely anyone uses it. You should be looking at .com, .net or .org domain names. A .com is so much more memorable that its worth going for one even if its not the exact domain you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It means, if someone or a company owns legal rights to a brand, Fictional Character (from a novel or movie), or it is their personal name (many artists use their name for their domain name), then that person or company can legally challenge you, perhaps obtaining the domain name themselves.

You would be able to register 'AndrewMichaelRobertson.name' without question, but if your name or company has nothing to do with Andrew Michael Robertson, then Andrew (if such person exists, or if an author creates a character in a book or movie) would be able to challenge your ownership of the domain.

*not to be taken as legal advice*

Comment: To be even more clear: If you register the domain before a fictional character is created, or a new person with that name is born, then a challenge is unlikely to go anywhere.

Comment: yes, if it's before. Although sometimes still may be be problems if the original domain is being used for porn, spam, unpopular ideas and so on. But usually, it's safe if it's before.